# How to make this hyperlink responsive. Thanks?

Tags: css, responsive

so thats my HTML:

```
<div class="responsive">
<a href="" 
target="_blank"><img alt="instalink" src=""
onmouseover="this.src=''"
onmouseout="this.src=''"/> </a>
```

CSS:

```
.responsive {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Thanks Guys.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "make responsive"?

Comment: so all of my website is responsive and changes when screen size changes. this hyperlink button just stays the same when im changing screen sizes.

Comment: Use CSS media queries.

Comment: my all website works just fine. the only problem is with <a> tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create media queries for it. Your rule is agnostic to screen sizes. Try this:

```
.responsive {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

/* On screens that are 992px or less, set the background color to blue */
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .responsive {
        /*Your rule*/
    }
}

/* On screens that are 600px or less, set the background color to olive */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .responsive {
        /*Your rule*/
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. my other images (logo etc..) are actually adjusting to the screen. atm my only problem is with <a> hyperlinks which I styled using CSS.

Comment: @YardenWeisman everything is styled using CSS ultimately, even if you use an outside library or a CSS generator. The above code should help you. Try setting ```max-width``` in the second and third rule, empty your server/browser cache, reload the page and play with the window size.

Comment: any idea why when i'm positioning my images they move when the window adjust? I mean the page adjust to different screen sizes now. but images moves when im adding a css position:; ... so weird. xD

Comment: @YardenWeisman if you create a JSFiddle with your situation, then I will probably be able to answer this question.

Comment: If u would be able to help me in private it would be gr8.